# Issue building Unofficial OpenGl SDK (glload)

Tags: opengl, gcc, build, sdk, makefile

I'm trying to build the SDK and am running into an error. Unfortunately google isn't turning up anything specific to my problem. I've already ran "premake4 gmake" and then run mingw32-make, and the below error shows up.

```
C:\Users\Austin\Documents\programming\opengl\new\glsdk_0_5_2>mingw32-make
==== Building glload (debug) ====
gl_load_cpp.cpp
In file included from include/glload/gl_all.hpp:9:0,
                 from source/gl_load_cpp.cpp:4:
include/glload/_int_gl_exts.hpp:4840:18: error: declaration does not declare any
thing [-fpermissive]
source/gl_load_cpp.cpp:4181:46: error: expected unqualified-id before '=' token
source/gl_load_cpp.cpp: In function 'void gl::CopyFunctionPointers()':
source/gl_load_cpp.cpp:7501:17: error: expected primary-expression before '=' to
ken
source/gl_load_cpp.cpp:10080:17: error: expected primary-expression before '=' t
oken
Makefile:135: recipe for target 'Debug/gl_load_cpp.o' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Debug/gl_load_cpp.o] Error 1
Makefile:16: recipe for target 'glload' failed
mingw32-make: *** [glload] Error 2
```

The errors seem to be related to the line, "extern _detail::Proc_glMemoryBarrier MemoryBarrier;", although I have no idea why.

EDIT: I ended up deleting this version of Mingw (supposedly the latest from their site) and downloaded an older version that compiled just fine. Not sure what exactly the issue was but if someone else sees this try this.

Comment: What version of MingW are you using?

Comment: I downloaded from http://www.mingw.org/ their latest version.